# How I can select which main file I must build in flutter during a release of a desktop application?

Tags: flutter, development-environment, production-environment

In flutter a made a linux application. Is consumes an endoint that varies depending the environment I need to build for. For each environment I have a different `main` file:

- For production I have a `main-prod.dart`
- For staging I have a `main-staging.dart`
- For local development I have a `main-dev.dart`
  All files are located into `./lib/ folder with the rest of source code

During building for desktop application via:

- `flutter build linux` or
- `flutter build windows` or
- `flutter build macos`

During `run` I can provide via `-t` parameter for example for local development I run:

```
flutter run -t ./lib/main-dev.dart
```

But how on Chirst's sake I can do the same for buidling as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you case you can build your application via:

```
flutter ^device^ -t ^main_file^
```

Where `^device^` are one of the following:

- windows
- linux
- macos

And the `^main_file^ is the one you use during` flutter run` in your case you have theese commands to select from:

| environment | file | windows | linux | macos |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| production | main-prod.dart | flutter build windows -t ./lib/main-prod.dart | flutter build linux -t ./lib/main-prod.dart | flutter build macos -t ./lib/main-prod.dart |
| development | main-dev.dart | flutter build windows -t ./lib/main-dev.dart | flutter build linux -t ./lib/main-dev.dart | flutter build macos -t ./lib/main-dev.dart |
| staging | main-staging.dart | flutter build windows -t ./lib/main-staging.dart | flutter build linux -t ./lib/main-staging.dart | flutter build macos -t ./lib/main-staging.dart |